# Check which value dummy variable R assigned to your categorical variable

Tags: r, statistics, dummy-variable

probably a very basic question, but I am performing a regression analysis with gender as one of the variables of interest. There are only two levels of gender in my data set, male and female. My understanding is that R automatically assigns a dummy value, 0 or 1 to this categorical variable. How do I know if male or female was assigned "1"?

I tried using the contrasts() function but it outputted

```
   > contrasts(df_logistic$gender)
       Female Male
            0    0
Female      1    0
Male        0    1
```

Comment: By default the first factor level is the reference level so in the case of a binary variable the other level has been assigned 1 in the model matrix.  However, the contrasts show you have three levels in your gender variable (run `nlevels(df_logistic$gender)` and `levels(df_logistic$gender)`).  You'll see you have an additional empty level `""`  that you probably meant to make `NA`.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [`?model.matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html).